# Is there evidence that competition between hospitals creates better quality and lower cost healthcare?

Tags: politics, healthcare

There is a debate in England, as the government is changing the way the NHS works, to introduce more competition.

The NHS will still operate as a single payer, covering the whole population: but providers such as hospitals will face more competition to attract patients, and the money that follows them. This policy is very controversial, and many believers in a centrally planned NHS claim these changes will destroy the system.

A recent Head to Head in the BMJ gave two experts the opportunity to express their sides of the argument. [Julian LeGrand](http://www.bmj.com/content/346/bmj.f1975) was in favour of competition:

> The fear of competition itself is misplaced. We now have considerable evidence that increasing competitive pressure does indeed provide the challenge that NHS hospitals apparently need if they are to improve.

He was opposed by [David Hunter](http://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.d3760):

> Gradually, the ethos of the NHS as a public service will be eroded and replaced with a different set of values. Whether this is motivated by naked greed...or neoliberal dogma permeating the political system, the end result will be largely the same and not in the public interest.

Some other countries have competition between hospitals, and their experience should be relevant to the NHS proposals.

Often the experience of the US is quoted as definitive proof that markets are a catastrophe. Here is one [contributor](http://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.d3760) to the debate in England:

> The government has failed to explain why the NHS, ranked overall second in health outcomes and first in cost effectiveness among seven developed countries (United Kingdom, New Zealand, Canada, Germany, Netherlands, Australia, and the United States... needs to involve profit making providers...The US produced the worst scores on these measures in this 2010 comparison and was ranked consistently lowest overall in previous Commonwealth Fund studies, in 2004, 2006, and 2007. The US achieves worse health outcomes than not only these developed countries but even impoverished Cuba ..., and at an annual per capita cost ($7410, 2009, ... more than double the UK’s ($3285) and 10 times Cuba’s ($707). The changes brought by the passage of the bill [to introduce more competition] would be to a more expensive system that will deliver worse quality of care: the worst of both worlds.

My question is this: is there evidence for the theory that implementing competition between hospitals will help quality or cost or both? What is the experience from other countries?

Comment: `widely agreed to be more effective than centrally planned systems for meeting needs` - The Police and Fire services are centrally planned. The public schools are centrally planned (by the public school boards). The standards of professional education and behaviour are centrally planned (professionals like doctors and nurses are licensed by bodies such as a national Medical Association).

Comment: `Does "it" [competition] help quality or cost or both?` -- I expect that **innovation** helps quality or cost or both. Innovation can be stagnated by central planning. Innovation requires finding and adopting new techniques, and investment in new equipment and consumables. Innovation is loosely coupled with competition: competition can result in innovation; innovations may arise in competitive environments; but economic competition isn't a necessary "sine qua non" for innovation.

Comment: Also (economic) failure isn't an option I don't care if a local taxi company, or fruit shop, or computer manufacturer struggles with being a losing business; but it's a public disaster if that happens to a local hospital.

Comment: There is obviously a lot of free-market competition in the health care systems already, for example: many medical equipment manufacturers; professionals being hired on a more-or-less open market, having been trained in diverse places; managers' bonuses and promotions may depend on how well they do compared with their peers. So the question, asking about "competition in general", may be too broad. Are you asking about competition as it's practised in US healthcare? Or are you asking about the type of competition which they're debating for the NHS?

Comment: `The US system is widely quoted as the definitive proof that markets don't work in healthcare.` -- I notice that the "seven developed countries" excluded France (which is one of the best, and better than the UK). The French system is a mix: some competition; some regulation; a lot of involvement by the State (employment taxes which ensure that everyone has basic insurance) and non-profit Health Insurance associations (many people have additional insurance).

Comment: "everyone has basic insurance" -- All costs are reimbursed 70% by the state. Visiting a GP costs 23 euros, a nurse 6 euros. Costs for chronic conditions (e.g. cancer, diabetes) are reimbursed 100%. The taxes which pay for this are similar to the taxes which pay for pensions. Private insurance reimburses the other 30%, pays for stays in hospital, etc. Doctors can charge their patients the standard rates which are recommended and 70% reimbursed by the state, or charge extra.

Comment: An example of state/private cooperation in France: the mayor (an important state official) of a village invites a doctor to immigrate from Bulgaria; he helps her move (helping her to buy a house in the village, etc.); when she hangs out her shingle, people visit (the village needed a doctor); her patients pay her 23 euros in cash, each (if she sees 30 patients on a busy day, that pays her mortgage and then some: she's prosperous); patients who pay to see her have their money reimbursed, 70% by the State and optionally by insurance. Village doctors who have bad reputations don't prosper so.

Comment: This is all off-topic for comments. Please use comments for improvements to the question.

Comment: @ChrisW The core question I was posing is about whether competition for core healthcare provision (hospitals, GP services et.) works. Clearly it exists in some places like the US, but US costs and outcomes are not a shining example of markets being good for the patient. Though we might also ask (though I suspect it would need a separate question) whether competition for medical equipment and drugs works like other markets to produce innovation or cost reduction. The second if far from obvious in pharma.

Comment: You'd expect that competition (for example each person being able to choose from among several GPs) improves or at least sustains quality. IMO small providers (for example retail pharmacies) can be left to compete, but large providers (for example hospitals) are essential public services and are too big/important (for political and social reasons) to be allowed to "compete" economically, if the type of "competition" implies potential failure. The actions of the State are important (for example insurance to ensure that everyone can afford medical treatment).

Comment: Are you asking for proof/study of a general/ideological theory, for example "Does competition work in healthcare?" Or asking about a more specific application of the theory, for example "What do studies suggest about introducing the type of competition which they're proposing for the NHS?"

Comment: I think your question would be improved by committing to a specific claim to be verified. I can't tell what that claim is, and you ask several questions at the end that aren't focused on a particular claim.

Comment: @ChrisW (and sancho). The specific claim is that introducing competition into healthcare provision (lets say hospitals and GPs) leads to improvements in clinical quality and cost compared to a system planned from the centre (like the original NHS). The opposite position would be that centrally planned and controlled systems are cheaper and better than those using competition.

Comment: One ideology says, "Competition is good, more is better, and less is worse." That some "competition works" is readily apparent in many examples, on large and small scales. The implied assertion ("... therefore more competition is better") might be logical if competition were the only factor contributing to the "good". But, every non-failed State intervenes, at national, provincial, and local levels, in regulating and financing its public health-care (and States' involvement is IMO evident, good, and necessary). "Competition" is merely one variable in each (national) system.

Comment: It's easy to find some evidence that "competition works". An example on TV recently was hospitals publishing their [nosocomial infection rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital-acquired_infection). However that publishing, the inter-hospital comparison or "competition", isn't necessarily economic in nature: local hospital chiefs and workers use the published measurements/data to improve their practices.

Comment: `The opposite position would be that centrally planned and controlled systems are ...` -- There's truth to that too. There are many ready examples of central planning being effective, for example national disease control and national health insurance.

Comment: I don't think there a single first world country where there isn't some form of competition between different hospitals and GPs. Someone who get Medicaid can choose between multiple hospitals. There so many ways to use competition that the question is way to vague to be answered definitely. I'm therefore voting to close the question.

Comment: All countries also practice central planning and government control, and invest public money. Generalizing "competition versus central planning" is a false dichotomy: health care systems have some of both.

Comment: @Christian I'm puzzled as to your reason for voting to close. There are clear differences between the extent of competition in different health systems. That should provide an evidence base for addressing which works best. "there are so many ways to use competition" is a reason toi be careful with the analysis not to not attempt it. More importantly, many systems don't have much competition so there should be an evidence base.

Comment: @matt_black : You assume that a single dimension of "competition" can be used in a meaningful way to classify different health systems. That category might be useful for journalists who want to write stories that interest readers. I don't think it's useful for actually understanding health care economics.

Comment: @Christian If your basic argument is that things are too complicated to analyze, there are a lot of health analysts and policymakers who disagree. And spend time debating the pros and cons.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm not proposing a binary classification just a sensible account of which systems have more and which have less competition. They clearly do differ and most people don't seem to find it hard to see how.

Comment: @matt_black : It makes a lot of sense to debate policy questions. "How much competition?" isn't a real policy question. Private insurance companies vs. single payer public healthcare would be a related policy question where you can actually debate pros and cons. You could also make the question about the precise policy challenge in the UK. Debating competition in the abstract just muddles the issues.

Comment: Perhaps your question is abstracted too far from the original (real-world) BMJ articles which you cited. The BMJ is debating "We should not fear competition!" versus "For-profit companies will strip NHS assets!". That (which is a narrower question than yours) is a debatable topic according to the BMJ, however debates are off-topic here. I take it that means we shouldn't try to expand on their debate, or to address (your) questions which have innumerable facets and answers. Fuel for their debate could include whether privatizing the UK railways led to the efficiencies which they hoped for, etc.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm trying to encourage a look at the evidence about whether introducing competition among healthcare providers creates benefits or not. Since some healthcare systems have this and some don't. This is not far abstracted from the UK debate and is more focussed than the issue of for-profit versus non-profit that often muddies the idea. And it isn't a debate about principles, but a search for *evidence*.

Comment: @Christian I don't want an abstract debate, I want *evidence*. And the evidence should address the simple question about competition among providers. This makes it narrower and easier to assess than any debate about single payer versus multiple insurers. The idea of allowing hospitals to compete **is** the central idea in the UK. I'd welcome any suggestions as to how to reword the question to make this clearer.

Comment: `suggestions as to how to reword the question to make this clearer` Maybe, "_What's the evidence for and against the theory that the [specific] competitive measures, which they propose for the NHS, will improve quality or cost?_" Or identify i.e. quote a specific claim of which you're skeptical. Avoid introducing  into your question additional unsubstantiated connections, for example equating the type competition proposed for the NHS with the types of competition which are implemented in the US.

Comment: `I'm not proposing a binary classification just a sensible account of which systems have more and which have less competition` Are you asking for a survey of all the forms of competition in all countries, and their effects? Or something narrower, like the effect of commercial competition on the life-cycle of urban hospitals?

Comment: @ChrisW There are not that many ways *hospitals* can compete, and the key metrics on which to judge success are not obscure (long term cost and quality of care). So a survey of the handful of possible model in different countries and the results they get doesn't seem like a ridiculous question.

Comment: I agree with the emphasis on _hospitals_: limiting the scope of your question to "economic competition between hospitals" makes it relevant the 'claim' in the article. Most of the controversy about "competition" in the US health care system is about the competition for health insurance (reimbursing the patient), not about competition for providing the medical service. In some ways the US system is even anti-competitive, for example people's health insurance is chosen by their employer and the doctors are chosen by the insurance companies; a patient may therefore need to change doctors if...

Comment: ... they changes employers; health insurance costs are a 'tax' on employers; people can less afford to be entrepreneurial or self-employed (they need employment to get group health insurance); etc.

Comment: Obviously a subjective question. Might be on topic at politics.

Comment: @DJClayworth Exactly how is this a *subjective* question? If those health systems that allow hospitals to compete have lower death rates (or other measures of quality) then we have clear *evidence* that competition works (or not). There is **nothing** subjective there.

Comment: People have very different opinions about what constitutes a 'good' health service. Death rate might be one, but far from the only one.

Comment: @DJClayworth we may have different opinions about what good is in a health system, but there are plenty of hard statistics that are not widely disputed that measure outcomes. Even if we weight them differently, there could easily be a hard definitive answer about who is good and who is bad. You can't just dismiss the whole issue as subjective (unless you have evidence that shows no metrics work well).

Comment: Even seemingly simple metrics are widely disputed as to their applicability. Look at any debate on the subject to see how stats can be used by both sides to prove their point or disprove the other. You might find it on topic at Politics. There are even different interpretations of your question" "Can competition improve healthcare?", Yes of course, in theory. In the same way that making private medicine public could improve it in theory. "Will that happen in practice for any given way of implementing privatization". No way of knowing.

Comment: I think this awnser can't be correctly awnsered for the reason that competition in theory might improve healthcare. But it all depends on the competition and more importantly on the greed of the competition. The competitors from an Oligopoly might work together driving the prices up for doing less.

Comment: @Lyrion The question isn't about theory: it is about *evidence*. There should be enough different versions of competition in the world's healthcare systems that there should be some real evidence about whether it works. I think too many commenters are being distracted by the *theoretical* arguments and not seeking evidence. That's why the question is here and not on politics.SE. Show me the data.

Comment: @matt_black That is because there probably is no evidence, nothing concrete probably. It is either made up or false data.

Comment: USA can not be used as an example of competition, since US insurers are barred by laws from competing with each other in different states. NJ resident can not buy medical insurance from a company that is in NY. Firms offering insurance plans offer different sets of plans to employees who live in different states. E.g., I have a choice between 1 PPO plan and one HMO plan. That's not a choice, it's a lack of options, to quote from a Bruce Willis' movie.

Comment: @matt_black : Whether or not the UK hospitals are run for profit doesn't have anything directly to do with whether those hospital compete with each other. In a fully private health system where insurance companies can make deals with individual hospital there probably less competition between hospital for patients then in a fully public system where a patient can just choose any hospital he wants.

Comment: @Christian Very good point that I totally agree with.

Comment: Hospitals don't really compete in the US - you need a "certificate of need" to open a new one and if the existing local hospitals object you can't get it.

Comment: A very carefully chosen set of countries there.  Why not just "all of Western Europe"?  Well, we know why don't we!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NHS has tried two ways of introducing competition: the evidence so far shows that only one worked.

1. Competition was first introduced between 1991 and 1997.
2. Competition was tried again in a different form from 2002 onward.

#### Summary of trials

A summary of these trials is in [Gwyn Bevan's 2011 review of NHS competition in the BMJ](http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d6470):

> During 1991–97, a period of limited growth in NHS funding, an “internal market” was introduced throughout the United Kingdom. It changed health authorities’ responsibilities by separating the roles of purchaser and provider of healthcare. Hospitals were made independent of health authorities, typically as directly managed units, which became NHS trusts regulated by the Department of Health. Health authorities contracted selectively with providers and constrained general practitioners’ referral options. However, general practitioners who opted for various forms of general practice fundholding were allocated cash budgets to contract for elective care and could choose where to refer their patients. Competition was between NHS trusts and private providers. NHS trusts were expected to avoid financial deficits but could not retain financial surpluses and hence arguably lacked strong incentives to increase market shares. There was little information on, and no external regulatory oversight of, quality of care.
>
> From 1997, the new Labour government abolished general practice fundholding and strongly discouraged competition in favour of a more cooperative model. Nevertheless, the distinction between purchasers and providers was retained, thus preserving scope for competition via selective contracting by purchasers (primary care trusts or PCTs).
>
> The “New Labour” hospital market, which applied only to England, was developed from 2002 onwards, a period of sustained increases in NHS funding (about 5% per year). Under this model PCTs contracted selectively with providers. Within the PCTs, practice based commissioners, which could be thought of as an extension of the general practice fundholding model, also contracted with providers but had indicative budgets only. Competition was again between providers, but there were more of them: NHS trusts, private providers, independent sector treatment centres, and NHS foundation trusts. Foundation trusts were high performing trusts that met Department of Health criteria for autonomy and were subject to approval and oversight by a new regulator, Monitor. They were allowed to retain financial surpluses and hence arguably had incentives to increase market shares.

Note:

- The 1991-1997 experiment allowed price competition but had poor availability of information about or regulation of quality or performance of hospitals. [Looking for a reference for this]
- The 2002-onwards experiment started with better information about performance and quality and national prices were set per Healthcare Resource Group (HRG) [similar to the US DRG]; providers could compete on quality and other factors to attract more patients. [Looking for a reference for this]

#### The 1991-1997 experiment

[Carol Propper summarises the results of the 1991-1997 experiment in this review](http://www.bris.ac.uk/cmpo/publications/papers/2005/wp133.pdf):

> The evidence suggests that greater competition was associated with lower costs (Söderlund et al, 1997). The bargaining power of district health authorities was lower than that of GP fundholders, and hospitals that had greater business from fundholders had lower posted prices (Propper et al, 1998; Propper, 1996). On the other hand, two large-scale studies of the
> association between competition and quality suggest that quality – as measured by
> deaths of patients admitted to hospitals with heart attacks – fell during the internal
> market (Propper et al, 2004, Propper, Burgess and Abraham, 2002). This combination
> of falls in price and quality fits with the predictions of economic theory: where
> demanders are sensitive to price and quality information is weak, *both prices and
> quality are likely to fall as competition increases.*

#### The 2002-onwards experiment

A [review](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/textonly/_new/research/productivity/management/PDF/Management_in_Healthcare_Report.pdf) by the [Centre for Economic Performance](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/) (at the London School of Economics) and McKinsey summarised the evidence linking good management practices to both hospital outcomes and costs. And it also **concluded that hospital competition improved the quality of management**.

In 2011 two groups independently reached the conclusion that **more competition both improved mortality by significant amounts and improved efficiency**. Zack Cooper's team published in [The Economic Journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2011.02449.x/abstract) (paywalled but their discussion paper is [here](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/28584/1/WP16.pdf)). They conclude:

> ...we find that mortality fell more quickly (i.e. quality improved) for patients living in more competitive markets after the introduction of hospital competition in January 2006. Our results suggest that hospital competition in markets with fixed prices can lead to improvements in clinical quality.

[Other papers](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/pubs/download/dp1125.pdf) from the same team concluded that efficiency also improves.

Propper's team independently reached a similar result ([working paper here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmpo/publications/papers/2010/wp242.pdf)). Propper [summarises](http://www.voxeu.org/article/healthcare-competition-saves-lives):

> In recent research along with Rodrigo Moreno-Serra (Gaynor et al. 2010), we look at all admissions to hospitals in the National Health Service – around 13 million admissions – pre- and post-policy. We find that hospitals located in areas where patients have more choice are of a higher clinical quality – as measured by lower death rates following admissions – and their patients stay in hospital for shorter periods compared with hospitals located in less competitive areas. What’s more, the hospitals in competitive markets have achieved this without increasing total operating costs or shedding staff. These findings suggest that the policy of choice and competition in healthcare can have benefits – **quality in English hospitals in areas in which more competition is possible has risen without a commensurate increase in costs**.
>
> [...]
>
> These results suggest that the details of the policy matter. **Competition under fixed prices appears to have beneficial results while competition where hospitals bargain over price and quality does not.** This in turn has policy implications for governments who are keen on introducing market forces to healthcare.

#### Conclusion

Evidence from the NHS (the 2002-onwards implementation) suggests that introduction of competition can have benefits for both patients (improved clinical quality) and governments (improved efficiency).

<sup>This answer is based on content that was originally contributed by matt_black.</sup>

Comment: Your arguments might be right .This might actually be a better answer than mine. I'm too close to the subject. +1

Answer (score 1):

**There is evidence that competition between hospitals can drive quality and cost improvements if the market is carefully designed.**

The question of whether competition has any role in healthcare provision is highly contentious. Many participants start with strong ideological positions and are more concerned with justifying their position by any means than in taking a skeptical and dispassionate view of the evidence. This encourages many debaters to make arguments based on economic theory rather than actual real world evidence. It is worth reviewing some of the theory if only to emphasise the importance of real world evidence.

**In this argument, theory is just a distraction**

One of the more vocal objectors to competition in the NHS is Lucy Reynolds. She frequently uses arguments from economic theory to show why competition can't work in healthcare (frequently quoting a [famous paper](http://www.aeaweb.org/aer/top20/53.5.941-973.pdf) from Kenneth Arrow in 1963). The most concise summary of her position is [here](http://bevansrun.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/guest-blog-competition-in-healthcare.html):

> 1.First, the assumptions underlying the market model really don’t fit at all well. These include:
>
> - No barriers to market entry or exit: but doctors need to be trained for years and hospitals need expensive facilities which aren’t easily converted to alternative uses.
> - Product homogeneity: but any clinician will tell you that for most conditions, there is great individual variation in the treatments needed for different patients, even those who have the same diagnosis.
> - No transaction costs, meaning no costs to provider or patient of
>   getting to the point where a treatment is sold: but clearly either the
>   patient must visit the doctor or vice versa, and the costs of
>   consultations and diagnostic tests are well above zero.
> - Perfect information about the healthcare transaction between doctor
>   and patient so that they can strike a fair price for the services
>   purchased: but of course patients don’t go to medical school or
>   receive clinical training in hospitals so they often have very little
>   comprehension of what is wrong with them. A substantial minority of
>   people in this country believe in homeopathy, crystal healing and
>   suchlike: they lack even a basic grasp of the science underlying
>   medicine, so how can they be considered to have enough understanding
>   to know if the doctor’s prescription is the best thing for them or
>   whether it is based on the best interests of the hospital’s profit
>   and loss account?

She summarises the anti-market case well. But there is a fatal flaw in the argument: *no other real world market even comes close to satisfying those assumptions either.* Apparently economic theory isn't that useful at telling us whether markets work.

John Kay makes a powerful argument for looking to the real world for evidence in his book *[The Truth About Markets: Their Genius, Their Limits, their Follies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Truth-About-Markets-Follies/dp/0713994894/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0)*. He rejects fundamentalist theory and focusses on what happens in the real world. He characterises the keys to market success as being akin to the forces driving biological evolution: variety and selection. These two factors drive improvement over time. But markets often need outside intervention to preserve these two key drivers, so getting social benefits from market activity may require careful government intervention.

The point of this theoretical interlude is that it explains why we have to interpret the evidence carefully: badly designed markets won't show benefits; well designed markets might.

**The NHS has tried two ways of introducing competition: the evidence so far shows that only one worked**

Competition was first introduced by John Major's Conservative government between 1991 and 1997, abolished when Tony Blair's Labour party won in 1997, but then tried again in a different form from 2002 as Blair realised the NHS needed stronger incentives to improve. There is a good summary in [Gwyn Bevan's 2011 review of NHS competition in the BMJ](http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d6470):

> During 1991–97, a period of limited growth in NHS funding, an “internal market” was introduced throughout the United Kingdom. It changed health authorities’ responsibilities by separating the roles of purchaser and provider of healthcare. Hospitals were made independent of health authorities, typically as directly managed units, which became NHS trusts regulated by the Department of Health. Health authorities contracted selectively with providers and constrained general practitioners’ referral options. However, general practitioners who opted for various forms of general practice fundholding were allocated cash budgets to contract for elective care and could choose where to refer their patients. Competition was between NHS trusts and private providers. NHS trusts were expected to avoid financial deficits but could not retain financial surpluses and hence arguably lacked strong incentives to increase market shares. There was little information on, and no external regulatory oversight of, quality of care.
>
> From 1997, the new Labour government abolished general practice fundholding and strongly discouraged competition in favour of a more cooperative model. Nevertheless, the distinction between purchasers and providers was retained, thus preserving scope for competition via selective contracting by purchasers (primary care trusts or PCTs).
>
> The “New Labour” hospital market, which applied only to England, was developed from 2002 onwards, a period of sustained increases in NHS funding (about 5% per year). Under this model PCTs contracted selectively with providers. Within the PCTs, practice based commissioners, which could be thought of as an extension of the general practice fundholding model, also contracted with providers but had indicative budgets only. Competition was again between providers, but there were more of them: NHS trusts, private providers, independent sector treatment centres, and NHS foundation trusts. Foundation trusts were high performing trusts that met Department of Health criteria for autonomy and were subject to approval and oversight by a new regulator, Monitor. They were allowed to retain financial surpluses and hence arguably had incentives to increase market shares.

Some of the key differences between the two exeriments are worth emphaising before looking at the actual evidence:

- The first experiment allowed price competition but had poor availability of information about or regulation of quality or performance of hospitals.
- The second experiment started with much better information about performance and quality and did not allow providers to compete on price (national prices were set per Healthcare Resource Group (HRG) [similar to the US DRG]); providers could compete on quality and other factors to attract more patients.

One factor common to both experiments was that the buyers were not *patients* but other professionals (often medics) who were well equipped to judge the quality and effectiveness of the clinical care on offer. This goes a long way to making Kenneth Arrow's objection to healthcare competition irrelevant: patients may be ill-equipped to judge the quality or effectiveness of treatment when faced with a doctor or hospital who is, but the actual purchasers are not.

The NHS is also distinct from many other health systems in that the patients do not pay either directly or via competing insurers: the Government acts as the universal insurer for the population.

**The evidence so far suggests that well-designed competition can save lives and lower costs**

The results from the first experiment in the NHS were mixed. [Carol Propper summarises in this review](http://www.bris.ac.uk/cmpo/publications/papers/2005/wp133.pdf) (which also contains many references to other analysis, some from the US market so is a useful source for further reading and more detailed evidence):

> The evidence suggests that greater competition was associated with lower costs (Söderlund et al, 1997). The bargaining power of district health authorities was lower than that of GP fundholders, and hospitals that had greater business from fundholders had lower posted prices (Propper et al, 1998; Propper, 1996). On the other hand, two large-scale studies of the
> association between competition and quality suggest that quality – as measured by
> deaths of patients admitted to hospitals with heart attacks – fell during the internal
> market (Propper et al, 2004, Propper, Burgess and Abraham, 2002). This combination
> of falls in price and quality fits with the predictions of economic theory: where
> demanders are sensitive to price and quality information is weak, *both prices and
> quality are likely to fall as competition increases.*

In summary, a market with poor information and weak purchasers led to some gains in costs, but compromised clinical quality. This is not regarded by many as a good tradeoff.

More recently, evidence has started to emerge about the second NHS experiment.

A [review](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/textonly/_new/research/productivity/management/PDF/Management_in_Healthcare_Report.pdf) by the [Centre for Economic Performance](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/) (at the London School of Economics) and McKinsey summarised the evidence linking good management practices to both hospital outcomes and costs. And it also concluded that hospital competition improved the quality of management.

In 2011 two groups independently reached the conclusion that more competition both improved mortality by significant amounts and improved efficiency. Zack Cooper's team published in [The Economic Journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2011.02449.x/abstract) (paywalled but their discussion paper is [here](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/28584/1/WP16.pdf)). They conclude:

> ...we find that mortality fell more quickly (i.e. quality improved) for patients living in more competitive markets after the introduction of hospital competition in January 2006. Our results suggest that hospital competition in markets with fixed prices can lead to improvements in clinical quality.

[Other papers](http://cep.lse.ac.uk/pubs/download/dp1125.pdf) from the same team concluded that efficiency also improves.

Meanwhile Propper's team had independently reached a similar result ([working paper here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmpo/publications/papers/2010/wp242.pdf)). Propper [summarises](http://www.voxeu.org/article/healthcare-competition-saves-lives):

> In recent research along with Rodrigo Moreno-Serra (Gaynor et al. 2010), we look at all admissions to hospitals in the National Health Service – around 13 million admissions – pre- and post-policy. We find that hospitals located in areas where patients have more choice are of a higher clinical quality – as measured by lower death rates following admissions – and their patients stay in hospital for shorter periods compared with hospitals located in less competitive areas. What’s more, the hospitals in competitive markets have achieved this without increasing total operating costs or shedding staff. These findings suggest that the policy of choice and competition in healthcare can have benefits – quality in English hospitals in areas in which more competition is possible has risen without a commensurate increase in costs.

and warns:

> These results suggest that the details of the policy matter. **Competition under fixed prices appears to have beneficial results while competition where hospitals bargain over price and quality does not.** This in turn has policy implications for governments who are keen on introducing market forces to healthcare.

To summarise: competition among hospitals can have quality and cost benefits, but governments have to get the design of the market right to see those benefits. This goes some way to explaining why the historic evidence is so mixed.

**Conclusion**

The best evidence we have from the NHS suggests that even the relatively timid introduction of competition can have benefits from both patients (improved clinical quality) and governments (improved efficiency). But getting this required careful design of the system.

**Endnote**

I should note that the results presented above are controversial. But they show that many of the theoretical objections raised in response to the original question **can** be addressed and actual experimental evidence can be brought to bear on a difficult and controversial area.

Comment: You emphasize the need for *well-designed* markets. This sounds like a [No True Scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) claim. To avoid that, you need to define what it means to be well-designed (in a way that can be judged *before* implementation.) (You'll probably also need to show that a *well-designed* competitive model outperforms a *well-designed* non-competitive model.)

Comment: You emphasize that it matters whether consumers can make an _informed_ choice. It's important to consider whether information is provided, for example http://www.cbc.ca/news/health/features/ratemyhospital/

Comment: There's a lot of subjectivity in this answer: "Many participants start with *strong ideological positions*...", "This *encourages* many debaters...", "In this argument, theory is *just a distraction*", "She summarises the anti-market case *well*", "Apparently economic theory *isn't that useful* at telling us whether markets work.", "John Kay makes a *powerful* argument", "This is not regarded by many as a good tradeoff", "I should note that the results presented above are controversial", "The *best* evidence we have from the NHS suggests that even the *relatively timid introduction*..."

Comment: I'd suggest sticking to neutral descriptions of the research. We're not Wikipedia, but this is a good guideline: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Words_to_watch

Comment: @Sancho You need to distinguish between opinion and subjectivity. There is a lot of opinion in this answer, but the question is do the facts support those opinions?

Comment: My point stands whether or not I view those sentences as opinion or subjective. Even if they are opinion, I don't know if the facts support those opinions, because for the sentences I highlight (for example), you haven't provided a reference. Who has said that Lucy Reynolds summarizes the anti-market case well? Who has said that John Kay makes a powerful argument? Who doesn't regard the tradeoff as good? Who calls the results controversial? Etc. As far as I can tell, this is just you. There's no need for editorializing in an answer.

Comment: @Sancho I think that is an infinite regression. You can't provide references to justify every reference. Read them and see if you agree or not.

Comment: @Oddthinking This isn't a *theoretical* debate but an *empirical* one. I simply point out that some market structures seem, experimentally, to give more benefits than others. Maybe other models can work even better: I await evidence.

Comment: @Sancho I was also trying to keep the length down. I can and will extend the answer if people object to the evidence.

Comment: @matt_black I don't object to the evidence, I object to the added bits of opinion. You could keep the length even shorter by removing that. Why not just way what Lucy Reynolds said rather than also saying "Lucy Reynolds summarizes the anti-market case well". Or just say what John Kay says rather than saying he makes a powerful argument. Or remove the entire pre-amble about the characterization of the motivations of the two sides. Those are the types of things I'm saying are pure opinion and don't add to the answer.

Comment: @Sancho: "Who has said that Lucy Reynolds summarizes the anti-market case well?" Making an opinionated claim that an author provides a readable summary is quite different to making an opinionate claim that an author is correct. You are holding Matt to a standard here that isn't enforced on others. If you feel this *should* be a standard, I think you should put your case on Meta.

Comment: Matt: "This isn't a *theoretical* debate." I don't see that this is responding to my objection. Your argument seems to be "Competition works for well-designed models, where 'well-designed' means ones that work." It's a tautology. It sounds like the real issue is good model design, rather than competition.

Comment: @Oddthinking I'm responding to a live argument along the lines of: "some markets don't work well, therefore no market models work well" (which has been repeated *ad nauseam* in the NHS). My point, in other words, is that we can't tell *a priori* (from theory) which work and which don't, so the only real test is empirical. Market ideologues (as opposed to pragmatists) tend to argue markets good, central planning bad. Carefull designed markets work better than planning, badly designed ones don't: evidence tells us which is which.

Comment: I agree you have refuted that claim. Perhaps your question should be clearer that that is the claim. "Carefully designed markets work better than planning" - you've shown well-designed markets work better than some central planning, and poorly designed markets work better than some central planning. You haven't shown well designed markets work better than *well-designed* central planning. So there is a confounding factor, that I posit (without evidence) is the most important factor. Unfortunately, it remains ill-defined, so there's no way of testing my claim.